# map not displayed sencha touch 2.3.1

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch-2

I have a list, on selecting an item from the list ([screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/uhz7j6705/)), details about that item are displayed in a container(con1) which also has a button in it to show position on map inside another container(con2), but on clicking the button the map is not being displayed, and no error shown also.

I.ve added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

to index.html file inside body tags.

[container code](http://pastebin.com/Ci4SDuaq)

[button tap listener](http://pastebin.com/j8axf5gK)

Comment: It is the same code in your two pastebin links

Comment: @DarinKolev changed the link.

Comment: anyone please help!!!

Comment: try to create an example here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home

Comment: @DarinKolev   [Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/49r)